# Переменная не видит значение разделённое точкой

Tags: переменные, vba

В тексте файла всегда присутствует строка с одним и тем же словом, я его обозначил как БУКВЫ, и символами которые находятся рядом с БУКВЫ. В отличие от БУКВЫ символы всегда разные. Я ищу БУКВЫ по тексту, записываю в переменную и из этой переменной удаляю БУКВЫ, остаётся набор символов под которым мне и нужно сохранить файл. Всё бы ничего, но как только среди символов появляется точка, переменная перестаёт видеть эти символы и при сохранении не подставляет их в название файла под которым нужно его сохранить.

```
Sub xxx()

Dim LR As String
Dim NewLR As String
Dim СохрLR As String
Set ПервоеОкно1 = ActiveWorkbook
Cells.Find(What:="БУКВЫ", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
LR = ActiveCell.Value
NewLR = Replace(LR, "БУКВЫ", "")
ChDrive "D"
ChDir "D:\"    
СохрLR = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=NewLR, fileFilter:=
"XLS Files (*.xls), *.xls")  
If СохрLR = "False" Then
End
Else
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs СохрLR
ПервоеОкно1.Close False
End If

End sub
```

Comment: вероятно потому что точка является спец символом, и ее нужно как-то экранировать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetSaveAsFilename воспринимает символы после точки как расширение, которое не соответствует фильтру, поэтому значение отбрасывается. Добавляйте принудительно расширение .XLS к полученному имени:

```
NewLR = Trim(Replace(LR, "БУКВЫ", ""))
If Right(UCase(NewLR),4) <> ".XLS" Then
    NewLR = NewLR & ".XLS"
End If
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает!